# How to create a Violin Plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, violin-plot

I want to create 10 violin plots but within one diagram. I looked at many examples like this one: [Violin plot matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/examples/statistics/boxplot_vs_violin_demo.html), what shows what I would like to have at the end.

But I did not know how to adapt it to a real data set. They all just generate some random data which is normal distributed.
I have data in form D[10,730] and if I try to adapt it from the link above with :
example:

```
axes[0].violinplot(all_data,showmeans=False,showmedians=True)
```

my code:

```
axes[0].violinplot(D,showmeans=False,showmedians=True)
```

it do not work. 
It should print 10 violin plot in parallel (first dimension of `D`).

So how do my data need to look like to get the same type of violin plot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to transpose your data array `D`.

```
axes[0].violinplot(D.T,showmeans=False,showmedians=True)
```

This appears to be a small bug in matplotlib. The axes are treated in a non-consistent manner for a list of 1D arrays and a 2D array.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

n_datasets = 10
n_samples = 730
data = np.random.randn(n_datasets,n_samples)

fig, axes = plt.subplots(1,3)

# http://matplotlib.org/examples/statistics/boxplot_vs_violin_demo.html
axes[0].violinplot([d for d in data])

# should be equivalent to:
axes[1].violinplot(data)

# is actually equivalent to
axes[2].violinplot(data.T)
```

[image]

You should file a bug report.